# Tests/ invariants for module isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

It two modules are indeed isomorphic, then it is often not too difficult to find an isomorphism since most of the time it is just the *natural* map. However, it takes some time for me to prove that two modules are not isomorphic.

Therefore I am wondering whether there are some convenient tools/ invariants to test whether two modules are isomorphic. Actually the only things I can think of are 1) rank:=size of maximal independent set; 2) torsion-free or not, and 3) the structural theorem for finite generated PID-modules.

However the first two are sometimes insufficient while the last is a computational pain.

Can someone share some better device? Thanks!

As pointed out by Martin Brandenburg, there are hundreds possible invariants, many of which I have never heard of. But I guess some of these invariants are more useful/ convenient than others. I am not asking for a complete list, just some useful tools or general strategies would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if the "torsion-free" observation included this or not, but isomorphic modules have to have the same annihilator. If you could conclude that they disagree in terms of homological properties (like projectivity, flatness or injectivity) that would be a red flag also.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Open any book on the theory of modules, it contains hundreds of invariants and properties of modules (which of course are in particular useful for showing that two modules are not isomorphic).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg True. But I guess there are some of these hundreds of invariants that are more convenient than others? Can you give some examples or some general strategies? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the "torsion-free" observation included this or not, but isomorphic modules have to have the same annihilator. If you could conclude that they disagree in terms of homological properties (like projectivity, flatness or injectivity) that would be a red flag also.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it should be mentioned that there is a fundamental difference between (1) and (2) on one side, and (3) on the other.

This is because (1) and (2) only test some partial invariants of a module. (Although (1) of course suffices to decide isomorphism for (unital) modules over a field, i.e. vector spaces.)

On the other hand, (3) yields a canonical form for a module, so that two modules will be isomorphic if and only if their canonical forms coincide.

Calculating a canonical form (which means, a distinguished element in the isomorphism class of an object) is possibly the prime method to test for (non-)isomorphism.